# Devexpress Checkbutton Blueline border - how to remove

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I am currently working on a devexpress project and I am using the `checkbutton` tool. I have it doing everything I want except for a very annoying sick looking blueline that shows up on `appearance.hover` and `appearance.pressed`.

If anything at all I would expect a color that goes with the theme but a constant blueline no matter what skin is selected is annoying and feels like an old html design.

I have tried setting the `bordercolor` and all but still.

Below is my code of what I have tried by far from `form.Designer.cs`;

```
this.cBtnFilter.AllowFocus = false;
this.cBtnFilter.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.cBtnFilter.AppearanceDisabled.Options.UseBackColor = true;
this.cBtnFilter.AppearanceHovered.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.cBtnFilter.AppearanceHovered.Options.UseBackColor = true;
this.cBtnFilter.AppearanceHovered.Options.UseBorderColor = true;
this.cBtnFilter.AppearancePressed.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.cBtnFilter.AppearancePressed.Options.UseBackColor = true;
this.cBtnFilter.AppearancePressed.Options.UseBorderColor = true;
this.cBtnFilter.ImageOptions.AllowGlyphSkinning = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.cBtnFilter.ImageOptions.Location = DevExpress.XtraEditors.ImageLocation.MiddleCenter;
this.cBtnFilter.ImageOptions.SvgImage = global::form.Properties.Resources.icon_filter;
this.cBtnFilter.ImageOptions.SvgImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 40);
this.cBtnFilter.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(355, 40);
this.cBtnFilter.LookAndFeel.SkinName = "The Bezier";
this.cBtnFilter.LookAndFeel.Style = DevExpress.LookAndFeel.LookAndFeelStyle.UltraFlat;
this.cBtnFilter.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
this.cBtnFilter.Name = "cBtnFilter";
this.cBtnFilter.PaintStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.PaintStyles.Light;
this.cBtnFilter.ShowFocusRectangle = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.cBtnFilter.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
toolTipTitleItem4.Text = "Show active Only";
superToolTip4.Items.Add(toolTipTitleItem4);
this.cBtnFilter.SuperTip = superToolTip4;
this.cBtnFilter.TabIndex = 39;
this.cBtnFilter.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Filter_Click);
```

The attached image is an example of when it is selected and when it is hovered respectively.

At the least if I could completely remove the blue line or change it to the theme color. It would be great.

**Am using Devexpress Version 20.2.4**

[image]

Comment: Have you made a ticket on their support site ? They are very helpfull in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how I solved this is by using the simple button instead and making it act like a toggle button.

this method handles the toggle for me

```
public Boolean buttonState = false;

private void ToggleButton()
        {
            if (buttonState)
            {
                simpleButton.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red;
                buttonState = false;
            }
            else
            {
                simpleButton.Appearance.BackColor = Color.White;
                buttonState = true;
            }
        }
```

this is the button

```
private void simpleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToggleButton();
}
```

here is the button in `Designer.cs`

```
this.simpleButton1.AllowFocus = false;
this.simpleButton1.AppearanceHovered.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Teal;
this.simpleButton1.AppearanceHovered.Options.UseBackColor = true;
this.simpleButton1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(524, 214);
this.simpleButton1.LookAndFeel.SkinName = "The Bezier";
this.simpleButton1.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
this.simpleButton1.Name = "simpleButton1";
this.simpleButton1.ShowFocusRectangle = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
this.simpleButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(157, 150);
this.simpleButton1.TabIndex = 2;
this.simpleButton1.Text = "simpleButton";
this.simpleButton1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.simpleButton1_Click);
```

Its quite straightforward. In case anyone has a better way or has need for this, knock yourself(ves) out.

Hopefully in the future, Devexpress will not force blue borders on us.